# Facebook status update box won't post certain sites

Tags: facebook

I've googled this but can't find any answers...What is the criteria for certain sites to be blocked when inserting them into the status update box. For example:

I type http://match.com and it loads the open graph data. I type http://ihookup.com (our clients site) and it doesn't load anything. The site doesn't have open graph data but it should still pull from meta data and images on the site and show *something*. So my first thought is that FB is filtering out explicit sites.

But then pornstars and porn companies all have pages on FB so I'm not sure what it could be. Can anyone weigh in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the site has been blocked. The following message is returned when using the Facebook composer

> You can't post this because it has a blocked link
>   The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe:
>
> ihookup.com
>
> Please remove this link to continue.
>
> If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

Use the [Blocked from Adding Content](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/571927962827151) form to resolve  this.